# GPS issue when Mobile Data is enabled

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, gps, motorola

I have two Motorola devices, a **Moto X2** and **Moto G3**, both with **Android M 6.0** (Original most recent ROM without root).

I have recently noticed problems with the GPS on both devices. Google Maps and Waze many times the GPS signal drops and can not determine the location.

In my test I could find that the GPS problem happens when the Mobile Data (only 3G) are active. Just disabling mobile data and GPS back to work with good accuracy and even on rainy days.

I researched on the Internet and can not find a solution to the problem. Already restored the network connections and even restored the factory settings. Also I have been tested to work with modes **High Accuracy** and **Only GPS**. The problem persists.

The issue is the same in both devices.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of research I discovered that the problem it is a conflict between some Android devices and some 3G networks. (In my case, in Brazil)

- Bug report (English): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81140
- TecMundo News (Portuguese): http://www.tecmundo.com.br/vivo/102386-sinal-vivo-interferindo-gps-celulares-afirmam-usuarios.htm
- Forum AndroidPit #1 (Portuguese): http://www.androidpit.com.br/forum/650921/motorola-moto-x-2014-problemas-no-gps-do-moto-x-xt-1097
- Forum AndroidPit #2 (Portuguese): http://www.androidpit.com.br/forum/654679/motorola-moto-g-2014-estranho-sinal-gps-cai-quando-ativo-3g-no-chip-da-tim
- Problem demonstration (Portuguese): https://youtu.be/CXkJUN8G83k
- Forum OuterSpace (Portuguese):
  http://forum.outerspace.com.br/index.php?threads/moto-x-e-moto-g-com-problemas-no-gps-tim.382402/

*Sorry about the portuguese content, but I could not find more details in english communities.*

I contacted Motorola, I will send my devices for repair. I believe it is difficult to be a solution, but I will update my answer whenever I have news.

**## UPDATE 17 Out 2016**

My Moto X2 was sent for repair and returned with the same problem, I'm trying a new contact with the manufacturer.